# ibdata1 file size not increasing while mysql import is in process?

Tags: mysql, wiki

I am trying to import the categorylinks sql file (almost 8 GB in size) from english wiki dump on my local mysql 5.5 server. I did it through command line. The import process is going on since last week and I can positively verify that the data is getting inserted into the categorylinks table by checking the max(cl_from) or using 'show processlist' which shows the current insert query.

The only confusion I have is that the ibdata1 file size in mysqlserver\data folder does not increase at all. I read somewhere that ibdata1 is the file that contains the actual data for an innodb. So shouldn't the ibdata1 file size increase while the insert queries get executed to insert data into the categorylinks table?

Comment: That really depends. The `ibdata1` file is the default file for InnoDB databases. However, the space is pre-allocated, and the file only grows as needed. If your initial file size is `50MB`, and you only have `20MB` of data, then the file will sit at `50MB`.

Comment: Also, you can tell InnoDB to use entirely different files with the `innodb_file_path` variable. You can also tell it to give each table its own file with `innodb_file_per_table`.

Answer (score 0):

Your my.cnf most likely has [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled.

With innodb_file_per_table disabled, here is what goes into ibdata1:

- Table Data
- Table Indexes
- [**MVCC (Multiversioning Concurrency Control) Data**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)

  - Rollback Segments
  - Undo Space
- Table Metadata (Data Dictionary)
- Double Write Buffer (Background write to prevent reliance on OS caching)
- Insert Buffer (Managing changes to non-unique secondary indexes)
- [Pictorial Representation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)

With innodb_file_per_table enabled, each InnoDB table and its indexes is stored in `.ibd` files under its respective DB folder. For example, mydb.mytable is stored as follows for [**datadir**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) /var/lib/mysql:

- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd`

Comment: This is somewhat true. However, the file may not grow even with `innodb_file_per_table` disabled, I believe. That would be the case if the amount of data in the database is less than the initial size of the tablespace. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html about "auto-extending" files.

Comment: It could still grow because of the Metadata, Double Write Buffer, Insert buffer, and MVCC. It will just grow slower. If a mysqldump is reloaded, it is possible for the chunk of rows for each extended INSERT to be small enough to be process without additional growth. If data is wide enough, then growth will indeed come.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understand what you mean. The MySQL documentation implies that the file only grows by a constant amount as needed. It doesn't say that some components don't count toward this limit. I haven't given enough attention to this aspect of the DB server to know exactly how it works. If you are simply implying that `data` is always coexisting with `metadata` and `administrative information`, then I agree with that.

Comment: I am adding some more details. I do not have innodb_file_per_table enabled and I do not see any separate ibd files for each table. The date modified for ibddata1 file changes every minute but the size does not increase even a single bit (which is almost 53GB). I am monitoring since 4-5 days now. Maybe, the raw data is already copied in that file first and the only thing that is being done now is index management or points that are mentioned above in the answer which might only require data reshuffling in the worst case? (I am totally new to this so bear with me please).